# Want to make navigation dynamic in MainLayout (Blazor.net)

Tags: layout, dynamic, navigation, blazor

Fail to make navigation in Blazor.net (Core 3.0 alpha 6) dynmic (loaded by Http Get Method)

I tried to include in "MainLayout.razor" file of default blazor project template the following dynamic loop.

```
the @body content was loaded correctly but navigation menu remains empty...

@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using Pegasus.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http

<div class="sidebar">
  @if (categories == null)
  {
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
  }
  else
  {
    @foreach (var category in categories)
    {
      <div>@category.Name</div>
    }
  }

</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="top-row px-4">
    <a href="http://blazor.net" target="_blank" class="ml-md-   auto">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content px-4">
    @Body
  </div>
</div>

@code{
  gb_Category[] categories;

  protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Test");

    var storeId = new Guid("c72d9757-98d5-4da2-89ea-2ffe44490162");

    categories = await Http.GetJsonAsync<gb_Category[]>($"api/Category/actives/{storeId}");
  }
}
```

No error message but empty navigation menu and I don't know why exaclty right now...

Same code runs if I put it into @page "/" but within @body of the MainLayout...
Goal is to load navigation items dynamic via Http and afterwards navigate through main data (@page's).

Thx

Comment: Did you verify that your categories array is populated with data retrieved from the database ? Otherwise, there is no reason why the foreach loop won't iterate through the data and display it.

Comment: It whoud run, see [sample](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vvavn58b). To isolate problem, can you change `gb_Category[] categories;` by `List<gb_Category> categories = new List<gb_Category>();`  and set db data as `categories.AddRange( await Http...);`